# How to apply SSO (single sign on)

Tags: sql, asp.net, authentication, authorization, single-sign-on

I already have a 5 asp.net application developed under ASP.NET & SQL. each application has his private users tables "credential" to authorize the users on the login.

How can apply a SSO solution to cover the 5 application ? knowing that the same user has different access credential on each application "The username & Password" not same for the same user on the 5 application.

also if there is any third party tool to do that without change any thing on the 5 application, will be very good.

Thanks.

Comment: If the users have different IDs between systems, how do you know which user record on system A corresponds to the user record on system B?  E.g. can you match by SSN or some other natural key?  Or is there a master table that joins them all together?

Comment: Actually there is no master table right now, but we have active directory on our company.

Comment: Either there needs to be some data item in common across systems or you will have to provide a user interface for a user to link existing accounts to their SSO profile.  Which way were you going to go?

Comment: i don't need the user do any thing, so it's my responsibility.

Comment: Do you have a programmatic way to support this? Or do you mean you're going to sit on the phone and manually link up each user's accounts?

Comment: i hope to find a programmatic way to do that, do you know how ?

Comment: What I am telling you is that it is not possible programmatically unless there is some data element in common across the profiles. You either need to find one (e.g. social security number, or maybe email address) or you will need a small data migration/conversion effort to create one, and it may require manual intervention, e.g. checking to see if first and last names match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Identity Server for this purpose (here https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/ is documentation for version 3 and you can find there how to run authorization in your APP).

The identity server provide **IdentityServerOptions** object where you can define some stuff. But for you will be most important **Factory** property where you can configure Identity Server behavior.

Here is example:

```cs
public class Factory
{
    public static IdentityServerServiceFactory Create()
    {
        var factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory();

        // Users are taken from custom UserService which implements IUserService
        var userService = new YourUserService();

        factory.UserService = new Registration<IUserService>(resolver => userService);

        // Custom view service, for custom login views
        factory.ViewService = new Registration<IViewService>(typeof(YourViewService));

        // Register for Identity Server clients (applications which Identity Server recognize and scopes
        factory.UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get());
        factory.UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

Where **YourUserService** will implemtent **IUserService** (provided by Identity Server) where you can authorize users how you need, in methods **AuthenticateLocalAsync** and **GetProfileDataAsync** you can do your own logic for authentication.

And using of the **Factory** in **Startup** class for Identity Server project

```cs
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var options = new IdentityServerOptions
    {
        SiteName = "IdentityServer",
        SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
        EnableWelcomePage = false,
        Factory = Factory.Create(),                
        AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
        {
           EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
           EnableSignOutPrompt = false,
        },
    };

    app.UseIdentityServer(options);
}
```

Here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/CustomUserService you can find some exmaple of this using own UserService

Also here https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples are more examples how to working with Identity Server.

Only bad thing is that in every application you must configure using Identity Server as authentication service so you must change existing apps.